# PHP While with hyphen add and lowercase

Tags: php, preg-replace, lowercase

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong with the Lowercase string?

The Preg_replace works but when I add the stringtolower it breaks with the message.
" unexpected 'strtolower' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'"

```
            <?php
            while($row10=mysql_fetch_array($result10))
            {
            echo "<a href=\"" . string strtolower (preg_replace('#[ -]+#', '-', $row10['english_navn'])); . ".php\"><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"large-3 columns\"><div class=\"b\"><br />" . $row10['chapter'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class=\"large-9 columns\"><h2>" . $row10['english_navn'] .     "</h2></div></div></a>";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Echoing HTML in that way will cause you future problems. Consider echoing directly HTML by closing temporary `?>`, rendering HTML and opening again `<?php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed your code for you. Next time i recommend using single quotes for a string so you dont have to use `\"` for html attributes

```
<?php
while($row10=mysql_fetch_array($result10))
{
    echo "<a href=\"" . strtolower(preg_replace('#[ \-]+#', '-', $row10['english_navn'])) . ".php\"><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"large-3 columns\"><div class=\"b\"><br />" . $row10['chapter'] . "</div></div>";
    echo "<div class=\"large-9 columns\"><h2>" . $row10['english_navn'] . "</h2></div></div></a>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have

```
string strtolower (...
```

or can you take 'string' out?

```
 echo "<a href=\"" . strtolower (preg_replace('#[ -]+#', '-', $row10['english_navn'])) . ".php\"><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"large-3 columns\"><div class=\"b\"><br />" . $row10['chapter'] . "</div></div>";
```

Comment: Still incorrect. Look at your second code block. after where the strtolower function closes.